# Average transmission trials given packet loss probability

Tags: probability, statistics, network

I'm in my intro to Networking course. And i'm at a loss for this most likely rudimentary Question.

If the packet loss probability is [0.3], then how many trails would a transmitter on average have to make?

I can find out that **the answer is 1.429** through the text book. But i have no idea how they got to that sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability of success in $0.7$. The distribution of number of trials until success is geometric with parameter of $0.7$.  So the expected value of trials until success is $\frac{1}{0.7}$.